# How to hide React Native NavigationBar

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigationbar

I have NavigatorIOS under Navigator and would like to hide Navigator's NavigationBar to use NavigatorIOS's bar. Is there any way to do this?

This is [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eugz8bx5tz1px1p/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%202015-05-13%207.25.49.png) that I've seen. I need backend of NavigatorIOS..

The structure that I want to build is the following:

```
├── NavigatorRoute1
│   ├── NavigatorIOSRoute1
│   ├── NavigatorIOSRoute2
│   └── NavigatorIOSRoute3
└── NavigatorRoute2
```

The code that I have is the below. (Basically obtained from UIExplore examples.

#### Navigator

```
render: function(){
return (
  <Navigator
    initialRoute={ROUTE_STACK[this.getInitialRouteIndex()]}
    initialRouteStack={ROUTE_STACK}
    style={styles.container}
    renderScene={this.renderScene}
    navigationBar={
      <Navigator.NavigationBar
        routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
        style={styles.navBar}
      />
    }
  />
);
}
```

#### NavigatorIOS

```
render: function(){
var nav = this.props.navigator;
 return (
  <NavigatorIOS
    style={styles.container}
    ref="nav"
    initialRoute={{
      component: UserSetting,
      rightButtonTitle: 'Done',
      title: 'My View Title',
      passProps: {nav: nav},
    }}
    tintColor="#FFFFFF"
    barTintColor="#183E63"
    titleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
  />
);
```

}

### UPDATE with my solution

I added a function to change state that handle rendering of Navigator and pass the prop to the component to change the state.

```
hideNavBar: function(){
  this.setState({hideNavBar: true});
},
render: function(){
 if ( this.state.hideNavBar === true ) {
  return (
    <Navigator
      initialRoute={ROUTE_STACK[0]}
      initialRouteStack={ROUTE_STACK}
      renderScene={this.renderScene}
    />
  );
 }else{
  return (
    <Navigator
      initialRoute={ROUTE_STACK[this.getInitialRouteIndex()]}
      initialRouteStack={ROUTE_STACK}
      style={styles.container}
      renderScene={this.renderScene}
      navigationBar={
        <Navigator.NavigationBar
          routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
          style={styles.navBar}
        />
      }
    />
  );
}
```

}

and

```
render: function(){
 var hideNavBar = this.props.hideNavBar;
 return (
  <NavigatorIOS
    style={styles.container}
    initialRoute={{
      component: UserSetting,
      rightButtonTitle: 'Done',
      title: 'My View Title',
      passProps: {hideNavBar: hideNavBar},
    }}
    tintColor="#FFFFFF"
    barTintColor="#183E63"
    titleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
  />
 );
```

}

Comment: How do you call the `hideNavBar` function that you created? My project is modular and I need to call it from a component from another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Navigator class  it looks like you're passing in a navigation bar. You can add logic there to pass in either Navigator.NavigationBar or your NavigatorIOS bar depending on which you'd like to use. To do that you'd need to specify a state variable in Navigator that you'd update when you want the bar to change.

Answer (score 26):

Because some old methods are deprecated i used stacknavigator. 
It works for me, if you are using StackNavigator.

```
//******For Older Versions. But Will be Deprecated in future*******
//static navigationOptions = { title: 'Welcome', header: null };

//For Latest Version Use:
static navigationOptions = { title: 'Welcome', headerShown: false};
```

Feel free to contact, if any issue.

Comment: Hey! Your solution is simple and works the best for me. Gave you an upvote :). What do you do to prevent notification bar overlapping with navigation bar on android?

Comment: Nothing else actually worked for me but this. I'm using react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.51.0
Using StackNavigator of course

Answer (score 21):

I solved this by defining a custom NavigationBar which can inspect the current route. Would look something like this:

```
class NavigationBar extends Navigator.NavigationBar {
  render() {
    var routes = this.props.navState.routeStack;

    if (routes.length) {
      var route = routes[routes.length - 1];

      if (route.display === false) {
        return null;
      }
    }

    return super.render();
  }
}
```

Using your example:

```
render: function(){
  return (
    <Navigator
      initialRoute={{
        component: UserSetting,
        rightButtonTitle: 'Done',
        title: 'My View Title',
        display: false,
      }}
      style={styles.container}
      renderScene={this.renderScene}
      navigationBar={
        <NavigationBar
          routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
          style={styles.navBar}
        />
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add that I've tried to rely on ```this.props.navState.presentedIndex``` but at render time it was always behind the real presentedIndex. What I ended up doing is using ```requestAnimationFrame``` in render and check on next frame the correct ```presentedIndex```

Comment: @GastonM Can you please elaborate how you solved with requestAnimationFra‌me?

Answer (score 19):

**In the React Navigation (5.x,6.x) [Current Version Is 6.x]**

Set `headerShown` property to `false` to hide navigation bar as below :

```
<Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
```

complete example :

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';


// Screen
import LoginScreen from '../screens/auth/LoginScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const CareAndCarersNavigation = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

export default MainNavigation
```

**In the React Navigation (4.0)**

to hide navigation bar you have **3 options** :

**1.** For the single screen, you can set header null in navigationOptions

```
static navigationOptions = {
    //To hide the ActionBar/NavigationBar
    header: null,
};
```

**2.** For the single screen, you can set header null in createStackNavigator like this

```
const App = createStackNavigator({
  First: {
    screen: HomeActivity,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
});
```

**3.** Hide the header from all the screens in once using defaultNavigationOptions

```
const App = createStackNavigator(
  {
    First: {
      screen: HomeActivity,
    },
  },{
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      header: null
    },
  }
);
```

### UPDATED

As @DarthVanger said in the comment below, to hide all headers in the stack, use `screenOptions` like the following:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: To hide it on all screens use `<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>`

Answer (score 7):

I did this:

```
Dashboard:{
  screen: Dashboard,
  navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {display:"none"},
    headerLeft: null
  },
},
```

Comment: hi, this addition should hide the soft buttons in android? what does mean the 'left' in headerLeft? why can't I do only 'header:null'?

Answer (score 7):

**For the React Navigation 5.x**

**Hide the navigation bar in all screen**

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false
  }}
>
  <Stack.Screen name="route-name" component={ScreenComponent} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Hide the navigation bar only one screen or specific screen see the following code.

```
<Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="route-name" component={ScreenComponent} />
```

See [react-navigation-5.0](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2020/02/06/react-navigation-5.0/) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

If you use NavigatorIOS always, you can do it like this:

1. modify the file NavigatorIOS.ios.js as below:

   ```
   before: navigationBarHidden={this.props.navigationBarHidden}
   after:  navigationBarHidden={route.navigationBarHidden}
   ```
2. navigator.push({navigationBarHidden: false})

Answer (score 3):

```
static navigationOptions = { title: 'Welcome', header: null };
```

Answer (score 2):

pass this property along with navigator.push or initialRoute by setting it as true

navigationBarHidden?: PropTypes.bool

Boolean value that indicates whether the navigation bar is hidden by default.

eg:

```
<NavigatorIOS
          style={styles.container}
          initialRoute={{
            title: 'LOGIN',
            component: Main,
            navigationBarHidden: true,
          }}/>
```

or

```
this.props.navigator.replace({
        title: 'ProviderList',
        component: ProviderList,
        passProps: {text: "hai"},``
        navigationBarHidden: true,
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

use header: null for react-navigation, in your navigationOptions as follows;

```
navigationOptions: {
    header: null,
}
```

Comment: hi this addition should hide the soft buttons in android?

Answer (score 2):

you need declare navigation object like this .

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
   Screen: { screen: HOME},
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
      return {
        headerShown: false,
        header: null,
        headerTitle: routeName
      };
    }
  }
);
```