# how to hide NavigatorIOS in react native

Tags: react-native

i am troubling using of NavigatorIOS in react native,

```
<NavigatorIOS
      style={styles.navigator}
      initialRoute={{
        title:’xxx’,
        component:xxx
      }}/>
```

here component xxx is my starting file here i don’t want navigator,after this i am using login screen there also i don’t want navigator after completion of the these screens,I need a navigator in my screen.
How can i hide the Navigator for these screens any help much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show the hidden navbar in react native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017090/how-to-show-the-hidden-navbar-in-react-native)

Comment: If you are using StackNavigator then check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202705/how-to-hide-react-native-navigationbar/43935245#43935245

Answer (score 1):

```
<NavigatorIOS
  style={styles.navigator}
  initialRoute={{
    title:'xxx',
    component:xxx
  }}
  navigationBarHidden={true} />
```

Comment: hidding is ok but in third screen i kept like this 
this.props.navigator.push({
        component:xxxx
        title:’xxxx’,
        navigationBarHidden:false
      })but not working,ineed to show navbar there

Comment: You can send props in a component using passProps:{..}. I don't think you can use this.props.navigator.push({ component:xxxx title:’xxxx’, navigationBarHidden:false })

Comment: @HussianShaik navigationBarHidden is a prop of NavigatorIOS, not Router.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the navigationBarHidden value with a state

```
<NavigatorIOS
  style={styles.navigator}
  initialRoute={{
  title:'xxx',
  component:xxx
 }}
 navigationBarHidden={this.state.navHidden} />
```

Now set the state to true or false based on your screen. You might have to make the props bubble up to the parent Navigator.