# how to show the hidden navbar in react native

Tags: react-native

i am troubling using of NavigatorIOS in react native,

```
    <NavigatorIOS
      style={styles.navigator}
      initialRoute={{
        title:'xxx',
        component:xxx
      }}

  navigationBarHidden={true} />
```

here component xxx is my starting file here i don’t want navigator,after this i am using login screen there also i don’t want navigator after completion of the these screens,I need a navigator in my screen.
for hiding i used above code but to show it in child screen i wrote like this but not showing

```
this.props.navigator.push({
        component:xxxx
        title:’xxxx’,
        navigationBarHidden:false
      })
```

any help much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of issues when using NavigatorIos. You have 2 options:

1. Dump NavigatorIos and move to Navigator. I was in the same scenario as you. I was using NavigatorIos and I wanted to completely replace the scene. It was a known issue and since Facebook stopped developing it and moved completely to Navigator, I was pretty much forced to make the change.
   Here is more info: [Navigator comparison](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator-comparison.html#content)
2. You can use a custom navigator like this [one by Kureev](https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-navbar). However, you should take into consideration that the way he implemented it, the navigator bar is part of your view, so when you move to a new scene, the whole page shifts, including your navigator.

I tried both option #1 and #2, and ultimately went with #1 and never looked back. It feels much more native and there is growing support for it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: could you never mine, can you send any sample on navigator.

Comment: This is more or less what I use. There are probably stuff you don't need here, but it should get you started: https://gist.github.com/eyaleizenberg/cc68ed7d8e59b18a8d72

Comment: @eyal83 Using Navigator to show/hide `NavBar` on different scenes - one has to play with state and redraw, right?  Or is there any other way?

Comment: I haven't attempted this but i theory you can change the navigationBar method you could check if the new route has some parameter, and if it does, just don't render the navigation bar.