# Can i disable hardware overview button (a recent button) on a phone in react native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I need disable a recent button. It is possible to implement this functionality when using react native?
About disable recent button when use react native i didn't find any thing. The difficulty is that my project uses expo, therefore i don't can use native modules  [Image for the button which must to be disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh9zO.png)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to hide android navigation bar. There are 2 ways to achieve that:

1. Use React Native libraries: There are some libraries supporting you to hide navigation bar.

   - [Hide Android Navigation Bar in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046055/hide-android-navigation-bar-in-react-native)
   - [How to hide React Native NavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202705/how-to-hide-react-native-navigationbar)
   - [How to hide android system' s bottom navigation bar in React Native App without changing MainActivity? Maybe through AndroidManifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756960/how-to-hide-android-system-s-bottom-navigation-bar-in-react-native-app-without)
2. Write a simple native module to do that: First, you need to read React Native document about Native Modules for Android. If you know how to use that, you can start searching: "android hide navigation bar". For example: [How to hide navigation bar permanently in android activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity)

In case you have any problems about creating native modules, just provide information about them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i need disable phone button (hardware button). For understanding the question, I added an image in description the question.

Comment: Ok, I have update my answer. Just comment here if I misunderstood your problem.